How to listen on both localhost, IPv4 and IPv6 at the same time with 1 configuration line?
SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9100
SocksPort [::]:9100

Works as expected. Listens on both, 127.0.0.1 and :::9100. But how to combine both into the same command?
According to ticket Listen on IPv6 by default for SocksPort *:Port this should be possible.

I believe we implemented this.

Why not use 2 config lines? Because I have a lot of SocksPort and 1 line instead of 2 lines would make the config much shorter, simpler.
Here is what I tried already...

SocksPort 9100

results in: 127.0.0.1

SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9100

results in: 127.0.0.1 (as expected)

results in: :::9100 (as expected)
SocksPort [::]:9100


SocksPort *:9100

results in: Syntax error

I do not wish to use 0.0.0.0 because I do not wish to listen on all interfaces but on localhost only.
How did I check on which ports Tor is listening?
sudo netstat -tulpen | grep 9100

What Tor version did I use?
tor --version


Tor version 0.4.8.12.

Tor upstream feature request: document how to listen on localhost on both, IPv4 and IPv6 at the same time using SocksPort *:Port

